# Resize grabber on HTML input form not working on phone browsers

Tags: html, mobile, user-input

I'm using the textarea html tag on a website to create a text input box.

```
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Hello..." required class="input1 input1B" id="textBox"></textarea>
```

The problem is the resize grabber that appears in the lower right corner of the text box does not appear to work on phone browsers and my client does not experience this problem on other websites.

I have tried setting the css for this item to include:

```
resize:both !important;
```

Doesn't seem to make a difference, and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile browsers don't support the CSS resize property - which is the very thing that gives you resize-able textareas.

Check out which browsers support resizing: http://caniuse.com/#search=resize

There's no simple way to "add mobile resizing". I guess you could still do it in a hacky way, but highly not recommended. The logic would probably be something like this:

- Set resize:none.
- Use HTML + CSS + an img (SVG) to create a little resizing tab at the bottom-right.
- Use JS to listen for drag events (you may need a custom touch events library) on your resize tab.
- Listener logic:
- Increase height of element by drag-y distance if drag is downward,
  but don't increase beyond the CSS / style max-height.
  Decrease height
  of element by drag-y distance if drag is upward, but don't decrease
  beyond the CSS / style min-height.
- Similarly, increase width if drag
  is to the right, but don't increase beyond the set max-width.
- Similarly, decrease width if drag is to the left, but don't decrease
  beyond the set min-width. If the parent element is fixed
  width/height, don't let user resize beyond the parent dimensions.
- If
  the parent is auto width/height, you may have to adjust scroll
  positions accordingly
- if the element's dimension change happen to
  exceed the parent's edges. (You may also have to perform some field
  testing to observe if changing the parent element's
  scrollTop/scrollLeft screws up your drag detection).

All in all, I'd say it's not worth it to implement on mobile. It's also probably good to not allow resizing on mobile, considering the limited screen real estate. As for IE/Edge browsers, wait for the CSS module specifications to finalise and MS will probably implement it.